# Arrow placement issue in syntactic tree using tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-trees, linguistics, tikz-qtree

I am trying to create a syntactic tree diagram using the tikz-qtree package, but I am encountering an issue with the placement of arrows in the tree. I have tried several solutions, but none of them have solved the problem. Here is the code I am currently working with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.append style={very thick}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{level distance=30pt}
    \tikzset{sibling distance=5pt}
    \Tree [.IP  \node(subj){Mary$_1$};
                [.I$'$  \node(head_I){I};
                        [.AgrOP \node(obj){John$_2$};
                             [.AgrO$'$  \node(head-AgrO){AgrO};
                                     [.VP   [.VP \edge[roof]; {\subnode{t1}{t$_1$} entertained \subnode{t2}{t$_2$}} ]
                                            [.PP \edge[roof]; {during his$_2$ vacation} ]]]]]]
    \draw[thick, ->] (t1.south) to[out=-90,in=-90,looseness=1] (subj.south);
    \draw[thick, dashed, ->] (t2.south) to[out=-90,in=-90,looseness=1] (obj.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When I compile this code, the arrows connecting the trace nodes t1 and t2 to their respective antecedents are not positioned correctly.

[image]

I have tried using the tikzmark library and the `\tikzmarknode` command, and `\tikz[remember picture, baseline]` alternatively but it does not seems to help.

Could someone please help me identify the issue and suggest a solution to correctly position the arrows in the tree diagram?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I upvoted as you included a description, code and an image of how it looks, I hope someone can answer soon and hope that you come back here for any questions/answers you have :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the `tikzmark` package for this you need to add `[remember picture]` to your `tikzpicture` environment. Then after two compilations, the arrows should originate from the correct place.

But I wouldn't use the `tikzmark` package for this, but instead just base the starting points off of the anchors of the VP node, using the `calc` library to adjust them as needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.append style={very thick}}

\begin{document}

With \texttt{tikzmark}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \tikzset{level distance=30pt}
    \tikzset{sibling distance=5pt}
    \Tree [.IP  \node(subj){Mary$_1$};
                [.I$'$  \node(head_I){I};
                        [.AgrOP \node(obj){John$_2$};
                             [.AgrO$'$  \node(head-AgrO){AgrO};
                                     [.VP   [.VP \edge[roof]; {\subnode{t1}{t$_1$} entertained \subnode{t2}{t$_2$}} ]
                                            [.PP \edge[roof]; {during his$_2$ vacation} ]]]]]]
    \draw[thick, ->] (t1.south) to[out=-90,in=-90,looseness=1] (subj.south);
    \draw[thick, dashed, ->] (t2.south) to[out=-90,in=-90,looseness=1] (obj.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

Without \texttt{tikzmark}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{level distance=30pt}
    \tikzset{sibling distance=5pt}
    \Tree [.IP  \node(subj){Mary$_1$};
                [.I$'$  \node(head_I){I};
                        [.AgrOP \node(obj){John$_2$};
                             [.AgrO$'$  \node(head-AgrO){AgrO};
                                     [.VP   [.VP \edge[roof]; \node(VP){$t_1$ entertained t$_2$}; ]
                                            [.PP \edge[roof]; {during his$_2$ vacation} ]]]]]]
    \draw[thick, ->] (VP.south west) to[out=-110,in=-90,looseness=1] (subj.south);
    \draw[thick, dashed, ->] ($(VP.south east)-(.25,0)$) to[out=-85,in=-90,looseness=1] (obj.south);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 2):

`\subnode`, `remember picture` and `overlay` work as expected if one uses them properly. `remember picture` has to be an option for the whole picture. Almost certainly you want to use `overlay` only for the bent arrows. `\subnode`s should be used as you did in your code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.append style={very thick}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \tikzset{level distance=30pt}
    \tikzset{sibling distance=5pt}
            \Tree [.IP  \node(subj){Mary$_1$};
                [.I$'$  \node(head_I){I};
                        [.AgrOP \node(obj){John$_2$};
                             [.AgrO$'$  \node(head-AgrO){AgrO};
                                     [.VP   [.VP \edge[roof]; {\subnode{t1}{t$_1$} entertained \subnode{t2}{t$_2$}} ]
                                            [.PP \edge[roof]; {during his$_2$ vacation} ]]]]]]

    \draw[overlay,thick, ->] (t1.south) to[out=-90,in=-90,looseness=1] (subj.south);
    \draw[overlay,thick, dashed, ->] (t2.south) to[out=-90,in=-90,looseness=1] (obj.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't this what I said in my answer? Since the `\draw` commands are inside `tikzpicture` there's no need to use `overlay` to place the arrows correctly.